# add the same menu contribution to two registered context menus(in different views)

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have two views in my application.there are treeviewer in both the views on which i want to add context menus.
I registered the context menues using

```
getsite().registerCOntextMenu(menu,treeviewer);
```

in both the views
Now i added the menu contribution in plugin.xml file as

```
<menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?before=editions">
         <command
              commandId="com.eclipse.command1"
              label="action"
               style="push">
          </command>
      </menuContribution>
```

but this menu is shown in only one of the context menu not in both.
so is there any way to add this menu to all the registered context menus or using the id for menu so that they can be identified.

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to a group in `locationURI` then this group has to be present in the menu.

In general:

> Any pop-up menu which is registered with the workbench should also define a GroupMarker in the registered menu with id IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS[="additions"].

In your case, the group should be named "editions".

Comment: @user1097085 Does your command have a handler? Is it enabled? See: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework#Handlers

Comment: no handlers are there actually the prob now is...in menu1 the cammand is added and working fine..but in menu2 its disabled...now i tried to give id to the menus and putit in location uri as <menuContribution locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.menu1?before=editions"> <command commandId="com.eclipse.command1" label="action" style="push"> </command> </menuContribution>
where 

menu1=new menumanager(null,"manu1");

i repaeted this thing for both the menus...but in menu 2 its disabled.i am using the available command of eclipse

org.eclipse.team.ui.synchronizeAll

Comment: @umang If there are no handlers declared for "org.eclipse.team.ui.synchronizeAll" command then those are likely created/activated in some internal classes (if at all). Either way, it is likely that you can't reuse them. You could try asking a separate question with all the details...